# get max value record from table in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

How to get max value record from table in hibernate?

Answer (score 61):

You could use a projection:

```
Criteria criteria = session
    .createCriteria(Person.class)
    .setProjection(Projections.max("age"));
Integer maxAge = (Integer)criteria.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: Criteria criteria = getSession() 
 .createCriteria(Borrower.class) 
  .setProjection(Projections.max("brwrid")); 
Long maxBrwrid = (Long)criteria.uniqueResult();

Comment: its working fine. but null value returns, if null returns set value is 1 else max+1, how to do it.

Comment: `if (maxBrwrid == null) { maxBrwrid = 1; } else { maxBrwrid = maxBrwrid + 1; }`

Comment: This gets the maximum *value* of the field of interest, not the record (object) containing the maximum value.

Comment: please satisfys my need can you edit and improve the answer with `if (maxBrwrid == null) { maxBrwrid = 1; } else { maxBrwrid = maxBrwrid + 1; }` as @Darin Dimitrov

Answer (score 27):

AFAIK, Projections will only retrieve a subset of the columns (or is it just one column?) you want.

If your data object is like so:

```
class Person {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    ...
}
```

and want the oldest person in the table, the following seems to work:

```
...
Person oldest = 
    (Person) session.createCriteria(Person.class)
    .addOrder(Order.desc("age"))
    .setMaxResults(1)
    .uniqueResult();
...
```

The Hibernate log (with `show_sql`, `format_sql`, and `use_sql_comments` all set to `true`) shows

```
select
    *
from
    ( /* criteria query */ select
        this_.ID as ID1_12_0_,
        this_.NAME as NAME_12_0_,
        this_.AGE as AGE_12_0_
    from
        PERSON this_
    order by
        this_.AGE desc )
where
    rownum <= ?
```

Which seems correct. Note that this is on Hibernate 3.3.2 with Oracle 11 XE.

Comment: I don't think this one is a good solution. Because you have to order all the records to find the oldest Person. This solution may result in performance problems in large tables.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `max(...)` aggregate function:

```
select max(cat.weight) from Cat cat
```

#### Reference

- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [14.7. Aggregate functions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

Answer (score 6):

You could use sub-query:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE age IN (SELECT MAX(age) age FROM Employee)
```

Comment: I guess that the last occurrence of "age" is a typo.. `FROM Employee WHERE age IN (SELECT MAX(age) FROM Employee)`